# Can Npgsql and/or NodaTime perform a select on a timestamp column with a timezone offset with an Entity Framework model?

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, npgsql, nodatime

I have Postgres database that has a `timestamp with time zone` column, and the local time zone for each record is different.  I want to return all records in their 'local' time zone, and I've found out how using the `at time zone` keywords.

The query below is the raw SQL that I use to get this information, and I'm wondering if npgsql or NodaTime has extensions to produce the `at time zone` part of the query.

```
select
    e.type,
    e.description,
    -- note: `z.name` resolves to zone names like 'Australia/Sydney'
    e.date_time at time zone z.name as local_time
from events e
join sources s on e.source_id = s.id
join zones z on s.zone_id = z.id
```

Comment: Noda Time itself (the core project) knows *nothing* about databases. It's possible that the [PostgreSQL Noda Time plugin](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/nodatime.html) does, but it's not something I'd expect to see in Noda Time itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're asking about Entity Framework Core, the PostgreSQL NodaTime plugin allows you to write queries such as the following:

```cs
var events = await ctx.Events
    .OrderBy(e => e.LocalTimestamp.InZoneLeniently(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb[e.TimeZoneId]).ToInstant())
    .ToListAsync();
```

In other words, you can call NodaTime methods like InZoneLeniently inside your EF LINQ query, and the provider will translate that to the `AT TIME ZONE` SQL expression.

[Here is the full list](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/nodatime.html#operation-translation) of translations supported by the NodaTime plugin. [See this article](https://www.roji.org/storing-timezones-in-the-db) for more on using local timestamps and time zones with PostgreSQL.